# Search function for vertical or horizontal text

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I wrote the code below to search for values in a spreadsheet. For some reason, when I try to search vertically it searches horizontally instead.

I thought that changing `valores[cc][0]` to `valores[0][cc]` would do that but it's not working.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
function onEdit(e){
  var a = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var SearchText = "4"
  //x = mainSearch( a, 3, 1, "horizontal", SearchText);
  x = mainSearch( a, 1, 1, "vertical", SearchText);
}

//mainSearch( targetSheet, row, column, alignment, searchText)
function mainSearch( folha, linha, coluna, procTipo, procTexto) {
  if ( procTipo = "horizontal" ) {
    var alcance = folha.getRange( linha, coluna, folha.getLastRow(), 1);
  }
  else if ( procTipo = "vertical" ) {
    var alcance = folha.getRange( linha, coluna, 1, folha.getLastColumn());
  }
  else {
    Browser.msgBox("mainSerch com procTipo errado");
  }
  var valores = alcance.getValues();
  for(cc=0;cc<valores.length;++cc) {
    if ( procTipo = "horizontal" ) {
      Browser.msgBox("Horizontal --> " + valores[cc][0]);
      if ( valores[cc][0] == procTexto ) {
        return (cc + linha);
      }
    }
    else if ( procTipo = "vertical" ) {
      Browser.msgBox("Vertical --> " + valores[0][cc]);
      if ( valores[0][cc] == procTexto ) {
        return (cc + coluna);
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if ( procTipo = "horizontal" ) {
```

When you execute `procTipo = "horizontal"`, you're assigning `"horizontal"` to `procTipo`. You should only test its value:

```
if ( procTipo == "horizontal" ) {
```

There are three other place where you'll have to change `=` to `==`.

Some people prefer to use `===` because [it doesn't do any type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness), but in this situation `==` will work equally well.

You'll have to adjust the iteration limit in order to search through `valores` properly in the vertical case. Currently you have this:

```
for(cc=0;cc<valores.length;++cc) {
```

Replace it with these two lines:

```
var limit = (procTipo == 'horizontal' ? valores.length : valores[0].length);
for (var cc = 0; cc < limit; ++cc) {
```

Comment: HI <br/> I always mess with that sort thing, anyway i change that part of the code and now if i search vertically it always appear once the Browser.msgBox, when it should appear (in my case) 4, unless text is found .<br/> Something is still wrong <br/> Horizontally is working fine <br/> Thanks in advance

Comment: HI... The issue is still the same but now if i search vertically it only appears 1 msgbox (instead of 4 , my total columns atm)., Before was always searching horizontally ...

Comment: For some reason the valores.length is being 1 but i have A1, B1 and C1 with text... folha.getLastColumn() is returning 3... Any idea why length is returning only 1 ??? Think the issue is there

Comment: That's because you have `cc<valores.length` and `valores` has length 1 in the vertical case. You have to check `valores[0].length` when you're searching vertically. See my revised answer for a concise way to fix this problem.

Comment: ahh ok it makes sense indeed... thanks in advance i guess now it will work.